# How do I *temporarily* change the *console* keymap to dvorak?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, console, dvorak

I type dvorak, but I don't like to confuse other users by having it be a system-wide default.

I have a script that runs `setxbmap dvorak` that I can call when I want dvorak and likewise another script that runs `setxbmap us` when I want qwerty.

For X, that's fine.  How do I get this behavior in the real console (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F3`)?

i.e. how can I change the console keymap to dvorak *without* setting a system-wide default.  Having to sudo to do it is fine, but it can't be the default keymap for any console user.

Resources like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console) and [this](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/linux.html) seem to be explaining how to permanently alter the system but I need to change it on the fly temporarily.

In BSD this was possible by using wsconsctl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `loadkeys`. Use `sudo loadkeys dvorak` to switch temporarily, and `sudo loadkeys us` (or whatever your qwerty keymap is) to get back.

You can use one of [these methods](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/315/how-to-shutdown-and-reboot-without-sudo-password/) to make it so `sudo loadkeys` doesn't actually require your password from you (I suggest method 2.)