# How to increase the font size in text-only mode with high DPI

Tags: console

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo w550s which has > 200DPI.
When I switch into the text-only console (using <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> etc), then the text is so tiny that it can barely be read.

I have tried to fix this using this procedure: 
  [How do I change the font or the font size in the TTY (console)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console)

But from the font selection menu, no font that was significantly larger was available (I chose the biggest one from the list) and the text on the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>) is still too tiny to be readable.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console

Comment: The answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console doesn't help with a 200DPI display.