# HiDPI console font non-interactive

Tags: dpkg, fonts, console, hdpi

What is the correct way to non-interactively change the console font?

I have a HiDPI display and need a larger console font. I can set it interactively just fine using:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
# Select UTF-8 -> Guess -> Terminus -> 16x32
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
```

However, if I try to set it non-interactively as follows:

```
 $ sudo debconf-set-selections <<EOF 
 console-setup console-setup/charmap47 select UTF-8
 console-setup console-setup/codeset47 select Guess optimal character set
 console-setup console-setup/codesetcode string guess
 console-setup console-setup/fontface47 select Terminus
 console-setup console-setup/fontsize string 16x32
 console-setup console-setup/fontsize-fb47 select 16x32 (framebuffer only)
 console-setup console-setup/fontsize-text47 select 16x32 (framebuffer only)
 EOF
```

This does not work. Running `setupcon` has no effect. If I check `/etc/default/console-setup`, I see the font info is updated when I run `dpkg-reconfigure`, and `dpkg-reconfigure` also triggers `update-initramfs`, so it seems more is going on with `dpkg-reconfigure` that my `debconf-set-selections` does not trigger. How do I find these actions and trigger them after my `debconf-set-selections`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to do this in /etc/default/console-setup file, let's say if we're gonna to use Terminus 16x32 fonts, the command will be:

```
sudo sed -i '/^FONTFACE/s/^/#/' /etc/default/console-setup # comment out the old value
sudo sed -i '/^FONTSIZE/s/^/#/' /etc/default/console-setup # comment out the old value
echo 'FONTFACE="TER"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/console-setup # Set font to Terminus
echo 'FONTSIZE="16x32"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/console-setup # Set font size
```

And finally, apply your change with `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Also, Ubuntu kernels (starts from Xenial) will soon support FONT_TER16x32 for console display in early boot stage [1].

To benefit from this HiDPI fonts support, one just need to add "fbcon=font:TER16x32" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in
/etc/default/grub, and run `sudo update-grub`

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1819881

Comment: Either I've messed up my system testing this, or there is still another step, because this did not work for me. I edited console-setup per your commands, ran update-intramfs, rebooted, and still had a small console font.

Comment: I was using this command for console-setup on a freshly installed Xenial server and it works well.

Comment: I tried the above on a fresh 20.04 and it works so I'm marking this solved with my thanks!