# how can I increase the terminal text size on ubuntu server?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, fonts

I am logged into an ubuntu server, the only monitor available is an old tv. The terminal text is very small, if I didn't know what it was saying, it would basically be illegible. In the terminal, (not the terminal emulator) how can I increase the text size?

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and changed the font to fixed, and the size to 8x18, the largest available, but it looks terrible, its even harder to read than whatever the default was.

Ubuntu server 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HiDPI console font non-interactive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105052/hidpi-console-font-non-interactive)

Answer (score 1):

In order to increase the text size you may decrease the console graphic resolution. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server should help.

It's probably a good idea to make sure you can ssh into your computer before trying some video modes. Just in case the changes make the screen completely unreadable.

AFAIR, the default font size is 9x16.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and in the last step select the desired font size. Note that the available font-sizes depend on the font selected in the previous step.