# How change the font size in Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, fonts

What I'm trying to do is increase the font size, not change the resolution. I still want my resolution to be 4k, but I want a bigger font size. Is this possible?
This is the terminal, there is no GUI installed.

Edit: the answer was:
sudo vi /etc/default/console-setup
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="16x32"
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot

It would be nice also to change the console resolution but I don't know how in Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Comment: Do you have a monitor directly connected to the server, or do you connect via SSH?

Comment: This answer might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105052/hidpi-console-font-non-interactive Also if you type your questions heading into the search box above there are similar questions with answers

Comment: Can this be larger than 16x32?
https://imgur.com/a/iqQmaOk

Comment: Note, this is not a ssh terminal, it's the HDMI output from a capture card

Comment: I think I read 16x32 was the limit but I’m no expert on that.

Comment: The answer was as you said:
sudo vi /etc/default/console-setup
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="16x32"
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot

Comment: If this is an answer do not simply say in the question this is answer. You need to at the bottom of the question use the bottom that says to answer you own question and put the answer in there so everyone can see it.

Comment: @David it's done

Answer (score 13):

The answer was to edit the file `/etc/default/console-setup` and enter:

```
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="16x32"
```

then:

```bsh
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Font size was too big on a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 20.04 Reducing to 8x16 worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

Do help us out with the name of which terminal application you're using.

***Part I: Increasing the Font size of your Terminal window (if its GNOME):***

Here's how you can do it:

- Open your terminal window [Shortcut: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`]
- Click the hamburger option in the top right corner of the terminal window >> Click on Preferences option
  OR
- Right-Click anywhere within the terminal window >> Choose Preferences option from the context sensitive menu
- On the preferences window, go to "Text" tab
- Click “custom font” check box to enable the font customization and alter the Font style and Font size
- Click on "Font-size" input field >> Pick your font style and move the slider (at the bottom) to determine your ideal font size
- Click on "Select" to ensure your chosen font style & size get implemented.
- Close the preferences window and save your settings.

Your terminal should now showcase the new Font style and size.

***Part II: If you're talking about the generic font size***

- Install Gnome tool using the command: `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`
- Open Gnome tool >> Click "Fonts" tab
- Configure font settings for 'Window Title', 'Interface', 'Document', and 'Monospace' through this tab.
- Increase/Decrease the "Scaling Factor" to change the general Font size for your Ubuntu Desktop.
- If required, remove Gnome by entering the command: `$ sudo apt remove gnome-tweak-tool`

Let us know how it works out for you.

Cheers,

Manu

Comment: This will depend entirely upon which terminal application is used - and we don't know what the OP uses. Maybe you should specify that this is valid for GNOME Terminal (if that is the case)?

Comment: I'm talking about the terminal as seen on the monitor, no ssh involved here.

Comment: I think you mean the non graphical server “terminal like” interface rather than a graphical terminal where it would be easy to change font size