# Screen scaling problem in 18.04 on 4k screen

Tags: 18.04, monitor, scaling

My Ubuntu 18.04 came default with a screen scaling of 200% which is great, since everything is teeny-tiny if I set it to 100 %.

However, not all programs seem to respect this setting; see for instance this screenshot I've taken of my terminal to the left, and Arduino on the right:

[image]

Icons and text system-wise are fine, but the Arduino window has microscopic icons and tab text. The only reason the text inside the window is okay size, is because I've set font size to 30 pt!

How can I make the Arduino program (and others) respect my 200 % scaling?

EDIT: I don't believe this is a duplicate of a question about fractional scaling, as this is not about fractional scaling, but about some programs not respecting the 200 % scaling set in the screen settings.

Comment: Scaling has limitations. Programs not using the toolkit GTK3 do not obey the scaling algorithms. Tweaks are sometimes possible (e.g. setting your font size very high), but not always (e.g. have a high resolution icon theme). I run only HD resolution for that reason.

Comment: So the conclusion is that only programs that choose to respect the scaling settings actually do? This seems rather unfortunate to me; I believe system settings should be able to override individual settings.

Comment: Can we please remove the duplicate? This is *not* a duplicate; this question has *nothing* to do with fractional scaling, it has to do with two different scaling settings for multiple displays.

Comment: I agree fully that this question is *not* a duplicate of the other question. It is related to not all apps respecting the scaling settings of the desktop environment.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is something that is being addressed in future versions of Ubuntu? Is the development team aware of this problem? Is there a way to alert the developers of Ubuntu?

Comment: This is exactly the type of problem I have with xfig

So far I have

- installed `gnome-tweaks` to increase my screen font size
- used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to fix my tty font size

both tricks found googling, the second one is explained 
<A href="https://github.com/mpalourdio/xps13/blob/master/HiDPI/tty.md"> here </a> and <a href="https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console">there on sx</a>.
playing with xrandr doesn't do it either

Answer (score 0):

I would point out that the Ubuntu team have little or no influence on the Arduino team and both probably have code that will have to be reworked to support 4k displays.  I can imagine that some Arduino systems don't have the free memory needed to contain 4K displays.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Matlab R2019b. I managed to solve the problem by putting resolution to FHD and scale to 100%