# Is there a way to use a nerd font such as Iosevka in the TTY for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, tty

If not, what would be the lowest impact to get a nerd font working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts).

Comment: Shade aside, your answer implies the only way to use fonts for an environment that lacks a GUI is with apt-get, correct? The fonts installed from GitHub will not work?

Comment: ...here is another https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console?rq=1. You really do have to search before asking.

Comment: I understand that the question is asked in a lame way, but it is legit, and is not a duplicate of any of the two. I have my fonts installed. I know how to change font or size in the TTY, but I still don't know if there's any tool that converts TTF fonts to formats that can be used in the TTY, even after reading all the linked answers. I'm guessing it's impossible, because of limitations, but this question has no answers in the linked questions. Next time read before moderation.