# Can't get unicode characters to display on Ubuntu Server 20.04.1

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, locale, unicode

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 (no GUI) and want to be able to see unicode characters in the terminal. Just to be clear: I'm not SSHed into it, the terminal I'm using is the one directly on the physical machine.

I've Googled around a lot and cannot seem to get an answer that works. I've updated my locale to en_US.UTF-8 using

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I've also tried running

```
dpkg-reconfigure locale
```

After taking these steps, when I run the command

```
locale
```

Everything in the results says "en_US.UTF-8" yet still all unicode characters are output as: "◆◆◆◆◆◆"

I'm using this file (opening with nano or printing with cat) as my test to see if unicode works: [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt)

All my search results lead me back to askubuntu with answers saying to use all the stuff I've already tried. Anybody have any ideas? Is the default terminal provided in Ubuntu Server simply incapable of displaying unicode?

Comment: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`  please.

Comment: XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"

variant and options are both empty

BACKSPACE="guess"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the font or the font size in the TTY (console)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173220/how-do-i-change-the-font-or-the-font-size-in-the-tty-console)

Comment: I have the same issue as you

Comment: I think possibly the problem here is that what I am fundamentally attempting to do is enable Unicode fonts on the Linux console, but the Linux console uses VGA fonts which are limited to 256 or 512 glyphs. This information is taken [from here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console):

"The Linux console uses UTF-8 encoding by default, but because the standard VGA-compatible framebuffer is used, a console font is limited to either a standard 256, or 512 glyphs."

I really don't know if its possible to make this work without some serious hacking.