# UTF-8 Issue, don't know where?

Tags: server, samba, locale, nodejs, utf-8

I am running a node.js server and the following line just isn't working.

```
console.log("☺☻♥ مرحبا 你好");
```

I opened up the file in nano and cat on my ubuntu server 14.04 (no gui, no window manager, no kde, no gtk, no nothing, pure ubuntu server 14.04) and it looks like this:

[image: nano]

I have the file in a samba share and when I open it in Windows 8 pro it looks as so in notepad++:

[image: notepad++]

[image: notepad++ encoding]

This is how the samba config looks like this, the private shares do not have anything fancy or to do with charsets:

[image: samba]

Locale looks as so:

[image]

/etc/default/locale looks like:

[image]

And the following command displays a `Ô` in the ubuntu server terminal:

```
perl -CO -le ‘print “\x{d4}”’
```

Like so:

[image]

I use the command `start_unicode` and then hold in `ALT` while typing `1236` and got a diamond!

I ran the following:

```
sudo touch /srv/file.txt
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "\xe2\x82\xac"' > /srv/file.txt
```

This resulted in a very nice € symbol in nano however when trying to display the following ☺☻♥ it does not work (black diamonds)

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: its because editors like nano don't support it - hvae you tried using `cat` instead of `nano`?

Comment: cat displayed the exact same I'm afraid!

Comment: @Wilf, editors like nano support it just fine.  Is this over a local session, or ssh?  Typically this sort of thing happens when using a poor ssh client ( typically from windows ) that doesn't speak utf-8, or when using a bad font that doesn't support those characters.

Comment: @psusi the file works in Windows in notepad, notepad++, komodo edit. I am using standard Samba so it's not ssh as far as I know!

Comment: I mean when you open it in nano... is this in a gnome terminal on the server?

Comment: @psusi Ubuntu Server 14.04 via the terminal!

Comment: Can you try another terminal like Terminator?

Comment: @muru I have not installed a window manager as it is a server. I suspect that nor nano or cat is the issue as node.js also does not display the correct characters when running!

Comment: You were using the virtual terminals all the while? Then you might want to look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/23610/how-to-enable-unicode-support-in-a-tty.

Comment: @muru I must stress I have installed nothing but ubuntu server 14.04, samba and nodejs (in that order). Nothing else, no windows manager, no kde, no gtk, nada (I have updated the system though).

Comment: That's fine. I assume you are accessing the server physically?

Comment: Indeed! It is on a VM on my Windows 8 Pro laptop (virtual box). the VM however shouldnt have an impact on this! I also tried that link, no to avail.

Comment: I use the command "start_unicode" and then hold in "ALT" while typing "1236" and got a diamond!

Answer (score 0):

Your `LANGUAGE` value is invalid. I really don't know, but possibly it confuses your system. Since you apparently don't want to use a [language priority list](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) anyway, you may want to drop the setting of `LANGUAGE`.

Comment: I updated the /etc/default/locale to what it looks like now (updated the thread), then locale-gen followed by a reboot, still the same I'm afraid!

Comment: @KarlMorrison: Ok. It was a long shot. ;)

Comment: And I thank you! Everything is always appreciated :)