# Nano via the terminal, how to write special characters?

Tags: server, 14.04, special-characters, nano

As the title says; Nano via the terminal, how to write special characters?

I am having trouble trying to [debug a UTF8 problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491765/utf-8-issue-do-not-know-where-it-is) and would like to create a special character in a file via the terminal.

Anyone know how to make for example alt-code symbols in nano?

Answer (score 5):

If you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> you will get an underlined `u`. Then type a character code and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You can see all the unicode character codes here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

The part where it says U+00e9; you can type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> 00e9

Or even just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> e9

Then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I feel I am getting closer to the UTF8 problem, when I press CTRL+SHIFT+U in the normal terminal nothing happens?

Comment: I use the command "start_unicode" and then hold in "ALT" while typing "1236" and got a diamond!

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your issue. Unless you have already solved it? You want to display UTF-8 characters in the Terminal? Do you have UTF-8 Encoding enabled for Terminal? As far as writing them, my answer should explain that.

Comment: This sounds like a window manager feature unrelated to the terminal or nano, which are the point of the question.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Yeah. It doesn't work in nano on Termux on Android 10.